# Intended to be a limited loop, but seems to be infinite

Tags: python, list, random, append, generator

I wanted to do the following task:

> Given a number N, let's say it's 5. I want to generate a list with all numbers in the range from 1 to N (5) with no duplicates in a random order.

So I wrote this code. Using these debug outputs I realized that the loop is pretty much infinite, even though it wasn't supposed to be.

```
import random
def generate(n):
    amount = n
    print('Line 1 success') #TODO:DEBUG
    randnum = 0
    print('Line 2 success') #TODO:DEBUG
    finished = False
    print('Line 3 success') #TODO:DEBUG
    nums = []
    print('Line 4 success') #TODO:DEBUG
    while amount != 0:
        while finished != True:
            print('Line 5 success', amount) #TODO:DEBUG
            randnum = random.randint(1,n)
            print('Line 6 success') #TODO:DEBUG
            if not randnum in nums:
                finished = True
                nums.append(randnum)
                print('Generation', amount, 'success') #TODO:DEBUG
                print(nums, ' ; ', randnum) #TODO:DEBUG
                print('Line 7 success') #TODO:DEBUG
            amount = amount - 1
            print('Line 8 success') #TODO:DEBUG
            finished = False
            print('Line 9 success') #TODO:DEBUG
    print(nums)


generate(5)
```

It gives me an infinite loop and I have no idea why and how to fix it.

Why is it an infinite loop?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why doesn't my variable being appended to the list?

Comment: Looks like you have an infinite loop.?  If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like stepping through execution, setting breakpoints, and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

Comment: It is appending to the list - `....Generation -24 success
[5, 3, 2, 4]....` is one of your diagnostic prints.

Comment: I still only have 4 variables on the list. One of them doesn't append

Comment: Does it ever *find it*? How do you know it has found the last number and not appended it?

Comment: My "debug" also outputs the RANDNUM variable, which shows me that it exists but not being appended on the list

Comment: I added `print(f'found another {nums}')` after `nums.append` and got `...Generation -4 success
found another [4, 5, 3, 1, 2]...` so that **is** working.

Comment: The infinite loop hasn't been resolved still, but yep it's actually being appended. I feel dumb

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Why is it an infinite loop?

Comment: In the future please refrain from morphing your question as you get answers to the numerous problems in your code. One question, one answer. This isn't a discussion forum. My comment regarding using the debugging features of you IDE or learning the `pdb` module was constructive and would help you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for help @wwii! I learned something new and got some practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a minor change @ `amount = amount -1`

This way your list gets appended every time a unique **randnum** is generated.

Also I have updated the loop break condition to reduce the time complexity.

```
import random
def generate(n):
    amount = n
    randnum = 0
    finished = False
    nums = []
    while amount > 0 and finished != True:
        randnum = random.randint(1,n)
        if not randnum in nums:
            finished = True
            nums.append(randnum)
            amount = amount - 1
            finished = False
    print(nums)


generate(5)

OUTPUT : [4, 1, 3, 5, 2]
```

Comment: What if I remove the `randnum = 0` line? Will it stop working?

Comment: I have pretty much no idea what's time complexity.Will removing this line reduce it?

Comment: there are simple ways in which u can efficiently re-write your program. I would recommend @grumpyp answer to start with.

Comment: don't worry, you 'll find time for "time complexity" soon. https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-time-complexity-with-python-examples-2bda6e8158a7

Comment: I kinda like his answer but I didn't really want to rewrite my whole program and lose everything

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
import random
def generate(n):
  l = []
  for i in range(0,n,1):
    l.append(i)
  random.shuffle(l)
```

According to your comment, this should work:

```
import random
def generate(n):
  l = []
  z = 0
  while z < n:
    x = random.randint(0,n)
    if x not in l:
      z +=1
      l.append(x)
  return l
```

Comment: I want them to be generated in random order, but they seem to be generated in the same order.

Comment: @LeopardLGD check if this works for you, I just added something.

Comment: It doesn't output anything

Comment: @LeopardLGD - it returns a value - some would say a function **should** return a value. Try `print(generate(5))`.

Comment: just add `print(l)` before the return or as @wwii said wrap it in a `print(generate(n))`